# foreach, handle filled/unfilled textbox

Tags: c#, foreach, textbox

I have a panel with several objects (textbox, checkbox, labels). In the textbox you are only allowed to enter numbers between > 0 & < 10. In the next step I have to check if the user entered more fields as required. Because every textbox means the result of one task, but the pupil is not allowed to answering all questions, one must be deselected by him. Which he normally should counts with 0 or not filled. Currently, I can detect that he filled more textboxes as required, but it will always set the last textbox to "" in the row. But I want that the current selected textbox, will get cleared "". I know why he clears the last textbox, but I don have another idea.

**Here my listener:**

```
   private void textBox_KTUTasks(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ungZaehler = 0, punkte = 0, i = 0;

            foreach (object tb in ((TextBox)sender).Parent.Controls)
            {

                if (tb is TextBox)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)tb).Text)  && ((TextBox)tb).Text != "0")
                    {
                        if (!int.TryParse(((TextBox)tb).Text, out ungZaehler))
                        {
                            ((TextBox)tb).Text = "";
                        }

                        if (ungZaehler <= 10 && ungZaehler >= 0)
                        {
                            punkte += ungZaehler;

                            i++;

                            if (i > 8) // 8 Tasks should be answered by him
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("One Textbox must be free/unfilled", "Wrong Input",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                ((TextBox)tb).Text = "";
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Not allowed to enter number higher than 10!", "Wrong Input",
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            ((TextBox)tb).Text = "";
                        }
```

Comment: The code is really bad and could do with a total rewrite.But if you just want to fix the specific problem, change `((TextBox)tb).Text = "";` to `((TextBox)sender).Text = "";`

Comment: Use NumericUpDown instead of TextBox for entering numbers.

Comment: thanks works, david arno. I would appreciate, when u show me how you would solve this in better code.